# Problem using Lyx command sequence for side by side figure

Tags: lyx

I have inserted this sequence command

```
command-sequence float-insert figure ; escape ; char-delete-backward ;
paragraph-params-apply \align center ; box-insert frameless ;
word-backward ; inset-modify box Box frameless position "t" hor_pos
"c" has_inner_box 1 inner_pos "t" use_parbox 0 use_makebox 0 width
"45line%" special "none" height "1in" height_special "totalheight" ;
word-forward ; inset-insert space \hfill{} ; box-insert frameless ;
word-backward ; inset-modify box Box frameless position "t" hor_pos
"c" has_inner_box 1 inner_pos "t" use_parbox 0 use_makebox 0 width
"45line%" special "none" height "1in" height_special "totalheight" ;
```

inside the mini-buffer in lyx to insert two figures side by side .

The command sequence creates side by side boxes as intended.

However, from reading the command, it is stated that `box-insert frameless` but still the boxes are generated with simple-frame.

How do I make the boxes appear frameless?

Additional info :

Command sequence taken from http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/CommandSequences#CommandSequenceFiguresSideBySide

I am using Lyx 2.0.6 in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the commands are case sensitive, so you need `Frameless` rather than `frameless`. I tested this with LyX 2.1 (on Windows), and then I also had to add an additional `word-forward` before  `inset-insert space \hfill{}`.

Updated command sequence:

```
command-sequence float-insert figure ; escape ; char-delete-backward ;
paragraph-params-apply \align center ; box-insert Frameless ;
word-backward ; inset-modify box Box Frameless position "t" hor_pos
"c" has_inner_box 1 inner_pos "t" use_parbox 0 use_makebox 0 width
"45line%" special "none" height "1in" height_special "totalheight" ;
word-forward ; word-forward ; inset-insert space \hfill{} ; box-insert Frameless ;
word-backward ; inset-modify box Box Frameless position "t" hor_pos
"c" has_inner_box 1 inner_pos "t" use_parbox 0 use_makebox 0 width
"45line%" special "none" height "1in" height_special "totalheight" ;
```

Comment: Tested your code in my Lyx and it works great. Boxes are created without frames as intended. By the way, what does the extra word-forward do?

Comment: @JagatheesanJack Without it the horizontal fill and second minipage was created within the first minipage, the additional `word-forward` steps the cursor out of the first minipage I guess. At least, it worked.